# Simple Calculation (Java/Android Studio)

Tags: google-apps, mobile, android, calculator

Currently the app divides whatever the user enters by 10, how can I make it so that 10 is divided by what the user enters.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button   mButton;
    EditText mEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int result = Integer.parseInt(mEdit.getText().toString())/10;

                        Log.v("EditText", "result is " + result);


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result is "+result,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (final NumberFormatException e)
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter a valid number",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    }
                });
    }



}
```

I want the event to happen in the "background".

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this the wrong way round:

```
  int result = Integer.parseInt(mEdit.getText().toString())/10;
```

What you are doing here is dividing the user's input by 10, not dividing 10 by the user's input as you requested. Further, this is an integer division: user input is parsed as an integer, and 10 is an integer. If user input is 3, the result of your computation will be zero (and not 0.3). Try to cast one of the operands into a float.

So, try out the following:

```
  float result = 10/Float.parseFloat(mEdit.getText().toString());
```